# How to type unicode character on mac without numeric pad?

Tags: macos, unicode

I systematically get into trouble on **Mac** to enter  **Unicode** characters in the very generic manner from quite common applications like Word, IStudio Publisher etc. Would it'd be possible to solve this issue once and for all OS X users.

*by the way I'm using Mac mini with OS X (10.13)*

*I don't have numeric keypad*

Answer (score 15):

First make sure **Unicode Hex Input** is enabled in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources`

It should appear at the left box with your other language keyboards. If **Unicode Hex Input** isn't available there, click the + button below and scroll to the very bottom of the languages list and choose others, select **Unicode Hex Input** in the right side details box and click Add button.

Now **Unicode Hex Input** should be available in menu bar among other languages, choose it and you will then be able to enter unicode characters by holding `Option` while you type the numbers.

Here is an example of Option+7767=睧 ;)